# Hausman test after including lags in my regression - different results?

Tags: poisson-distribution, stata, negative-binomial-distribution, lags, hausman

I have a panel data set with a count variable as my dependent variable. Consequently, I am now trying to identify whether I need to use a Poisson or negative binomial regression model and whether to use fixed effects or random effects. Based on my (unfortunately still limited) understanding, the `countfit` model seems to suggest a negative binomial regression is more appropriate.

Yet, based on an article by Allison & Waterman (2002), it seems that - despite over-dispersion - a Poisson distribution seems more appropriate when having to use a fixed-effects model. I have quite a few lags in my data to control for endogeneity, but am not sure at which point (before or after lagging) I have to run the Hausman test - my results differ based on whether I include the lags or not: Without any lagging, a fixed effects model would need to be used independent of Poisson or negative binomial regression model. After lagging, a random effects model is appropriate for both a Poisson or a `nbreg` regression.

To give you an impression, this would be my initial regression including time lags, of which I then store the results to use for the Hausman test:

```
xtpoisson trans L6.c.rpat_ln_rRD##L4.c.rel_ROA L6.c.rpat_ln_rRD##L4.c.sthom_all L6.c.rpat_ln_rRD##L4.c.rel_size_a_ln L6.c.rpat_ln_rRD##L4.c.zdebt_rat L4.c.no_SGA L6.c.rpat_ln_rRD##c.trans_e, fe
```